# Backbone - How to pass dynamic server JSON output from One View to another View as an input to get the another level of category dynamically

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to pass the JSON output from one view to another view. But I stuck here as I don't know to how move forward. It seems, some event handling, triggers may help. I searched, but I couldn't figured out! I pasted my complete code. Backbone+underscore+jquery front-end with restful back-end. There 5-7 sub-category level. When we print the main category, it should have a hyperlink to navigate to the next sub-category & the sub-category will have links to another level. I successfully got main-category output. Now the main category view has some JSON values to link to the sub-category. I just need some idea on how to pass the JSON value to the another view(sub-category view) to post it to server to get the sub-category list. Hope, it makes clear.

```
<body>
   <div class="page"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
        <% _.each(mainCategoryListResponseCollection, function(MainCategoryListResponse) { %>
          <p><a href="<%= MainCategoryListResponse.get('mainCategoryId') %>/<%= MainCategoryListResponse.get('rootId') %>"><%= MainCategoryListResponse.get('directoryName') %></a></p>
        <% }); %>
</script>

    var MainCategoryListResponse = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot:'/main-dirctory',
            defaults:{
                "clientCompanyName":"GOD",
                "clientCountry":"ALL Country"
                "mainCategoryId":"", // This Id from server is used to get the sub-category list
                "rootId"":''// This Id from server is used to get the sub-category list
            }

        });

        var MainCategoryListResponseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: MainCategoryListResponse,
            url: '/main-dirctory'
        }); 

        var MainCategoryListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function() {
                 var that = this;
                    var mainCategoryListResponseCollection = new MainCategoryListResponseCollection();

                 //  mainCategoryListResponseCollection.set({"typeId": "1"});
                    mainCategoryListResponseCollection.fetch({
                          type: 'POST',
                          data: JSON.stringify({'typeId': '1'}), //Passing the value manually here in the first parent view
                          contentType: "application/json",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (mainCategoryListResponseCollection) {
            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {mainCategoryListResponseCollection: mainCategoryListResponseCollection.models});
            that.$el.html(template);

         }
                      });       
            }
        });

        var SubCategoryListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function() {
                 var that = this;
                    var subCategoryListResponseCollection = new SubCategoryListResponseCollection();
                    subCategoryListResponseCollection.fetch({
                          type: 'POST',
                          data: JSON.stringify({'???': '???'}), //here I need to pass the dynamic value from the above view. The dynamic value should be like "mainCategoryId": "5", "rootId": "0" which is getting printed in the each loop down here. 
                          contentType: "application/json",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (subCategoryListResponseCollection) {
            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {subCategoryListResponseCollection: subCategoryListResponseCollection.models});
            that.$el.html(template);

         }
         });       
         }
        });

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"main_directory"
 }
});
var MainCategoryListView = new MainCategoryListView();
var router = new Router();
router.on('route:main_directory', function() {
    MainCategoryListView.render();

});
Backbone.history.start();

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have underscore template along with JavaScript? Where are you initializing this views? Which data you want to pass between views? When do you want to pass this data? Please read [ask] and add further info in your question.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. Please let me know if this still not clear. I am new to backbone. Sorry, if I am not clear enough. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you guys! I resolved the issue using router. Yes, values can be passed from URL to router & router transfers them to the view.